# Do the parts of a query string have a name?

Tags: url, query-string

For example, if you have:

```
?id=414&name=bob
```

ID and Name could be called the keys.

414 and bob could be called the values.

Do the ?, = and & have an official name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called `Reserved Characters`

See section 2.2 of this [rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>
> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
>   special characters. These characters are called "reserved", since
>   their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
>   purpose. If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>   reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>   forming the URI.
>
> reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" |
>   ","